# How can I rotate TIFF CMYK image in ImageIO or TwelveMonkeys?

Tags: java, tiff, bufferedimage, cmyk, twelvemonkeys

I need to rotate my TIFF image with color space CMYK. Standard Java ImageIO doesn't support CMYK TIFF images so I used TwelveMonkeys plugin. But it didn't help. When I tried to rotate my image I faced with an exception.

I do the following:

```
try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is)) {
      Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);

      if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Image type is not supported");
      }

      ImageReader reader = iter.next();
      BufferedImage bi;
      try {
        reader.setInput(iis);
        bi = reader.read(0);
      } finally {
        reader.dispose();
      }
      int type = bi.getType();
      BufferedImage newBi;
      if (angle == 90 || angle == 270) {
        newBi= new BufferedImage(height, width, type);
      } else {
        newBi= new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
      }
      //writing the image content to new buffered image
}
```

But it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0`. How can I create a BufferedImage for TIFF CMYK image? Or at least how can I rotate TIFF CMYK image?

Comment: Do you have a sample of your image? Which line is throwing the error? Why not use ImageIO.read( file)? Did you check which readers you have to make sure your plugin is installed correctly? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageReadersBySuffix-java.lang.String-

Comment: The exception is thrown by line `newBi= new BufferedImage(height, width, type);`. As I understand the problem is that `new BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType)` constructor doesn't support type 0. I don't use `ImageIO.read(file)` because I want to be sure that I use TIFFImageReader from TwelveMonkeys. I checked it and it's ok - I use right reader

Comment: Try using the [Apache Commons Imaging API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) but, for the sake of detail...[give this a full read](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMAGING-201).

Comment: Why do you need your new BufferedImage to be 'cmyk'? You could try using the [BufferedImageOp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImageOp.html) supply null for the destination and see what java gives you back.

Comment: @DevilsHnd-退した the OP is using [TwelveMonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys). Are you saying that he should use _Apache Commons Imaging_ instead?

Comment: [twelvemonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/0378f504e7bf0fde5e20c146fc357c66119b0b5b/common/common-image/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/AffineTransformOp.java) also has some image ops, that might preserve the image type.

Comment: FYI, the author of _TwelveMonkeys_ usually answers question tagged "twelvemonkeys" but it may take some time before he answers.

Comment: @matt thank you for the information about BufferedImageOp. I tried to use ColorConvertOp from Image IO and it successfully converted CMYK to RGB. If there is no other solution I will use color space conversion like this: ```ColorConvertOp colorConvertOp = new ColorConvertOp(cmykBi.getColorModel().getColorSpace(),
          new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB)), null);
      BufferedImage rgbBi = colorConvertOp.filter(cmykBi, null);```

Comment: @bepopov You should probably post the full stack trace. From my understanding, the problem isn't related to `TwelveMonkeys`, but the fact that any CMYK  `BufferedImage` has to be `TYPE_CUSTOM` (the constant value 0). And you can't create a new `BufferedImage` using the constructor taking a type argument for type custom images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate a `BufferedImage` in Java, the normal way would be to use [`AffineTransformOp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html). This will allow you to rotate any image without having to create a new image of the same type up front.

For an example see the [`TIFFUtilities.applyOrientation`](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/77a1745106df765193f9c9a514aac1b6f4c9e035/contrib/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/contrib/tiff/TIFFUtilities.java#L240) method in TwelveMonkeys "contrib" module. You can also just use this method directly, if you like. Just beware the input is one of the TIFF orientation tag constant values, not an angle:

Ie. to rotate 90 degrees (assuming static imports for readability):

```java
BufferedImage original;

BufferedImage rotated = applyOrientation(original, ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP); // 6
```

---

For the more general topic *"How can I create a BufferedImage for a TIFF CMYK image"*, the quick answer is use [the constructor that takes a `WritableRaster` and a `ColorModel` as argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage-java.awt.image.ColorModel-java.awt.image.WritableRaster-boolean-java.util.Hashtable-) like this:

```java
BufferedImage original;

ColorModel cm = original.getColorModel();
WritableRaster raster = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(newWidth, newHeight);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

You have to use this constructor, as any CMYK `BufferedImage` has to be `TYPE_CUSTOM` (the constant value 0). And the `BufferedImage`  constructor taking a type argument does not allow `TYPE_CUSTOM` (after all, which of the countless possible custom types would that be?).

Comment: Thank you a lot! Should I use com.twelvemonkeys.image.AffineTransformOp or java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp? Does com.twelvemonkeys.image.AffineTransformOp support all images supported by java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp? Or maybe I should use both of them for different cases?

Comment: Use only one. The API is the same. The TwelveMonkeys version delegates to the java.awt version, but supports a few extra odd cases using a workaround. But as less dependencies is usually a good thing, I'd say use the java.awt version unless you need the extra support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you would read a CMYK Tiff image with ImageIO, but here's how you could read and rotate the image using OpenCV:

Note that you would need [this dependency](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv) in your project.

```java
// Since OpenCV is a native (C++) library, it needs to be loaded before it can be used. Only do this once in your application.
OpenCV.loadLocally();

MatOfByte inputBuffer = new MatOfByte(bytes);
Mat inputImage;

try {
    inputImage = Imgcodecs.imdecode(inputBuffer, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
} finally {
    inputBuffer.release();
}

Mat rotatedImage;

try {
    if (angle == 0) {
        // Copies the image by reference as we will release the input image in the finally-block
        rotatedImage = new Mat(inputImage, new Rect(0, 0, inputImage.cols(), inputImage.rows()));
    } else {
        int rotateCode = Core.ROTATE_180;

        if (angle == 90) rotateCode = Core.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE;
        else if (angle == 270) rotateCode = Core.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE;

        rotatedImage = new Mat();
        Core.rotate(inputImage, rotatedImage, rotateCode);
    }
} finally {
    inputImage.release();
}

// Convert the image to a BufferedImage
MatOfByte outputBuffer = new MatOfByte();
BufferedImage bufferedImage;
try {
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", rotatedImage, outputBuffer);
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputBuffer.toArray()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    outputBuffer.release();
}
```

Also, note that the conversion in the last step to a `BufferedImage` uses the `png` file-format in this example. You can probably safely change it to Tiff, if you have the TwelveMonkeys plugin installed.

Furthermore, `Imgcodecs.imdecode` may change the color space from CMYK to BGR ([relevant documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)). Since I don't have a test picture available, you would need to test that.

Comment: They're using twelvemonkeys. They register it as a plugin/service provider and ImageIO will use it.